# How to make inline errors read aloud by screen reader tools?

Tags: asp.net, accessibility

I am doing accessibility testing. I created an email text box and added some validation as well. I want after typing wrong email as I move to next element screen reader should read the inline errors. I came across using aria-describeby and aria-live attribute but don't know how to use it in this code .

```
<asp:panel defaultbutton="btnEmail" cssclass="row" runat="server">
        <biw:labelui associatedcontrolid="TextEmail" text="Email Address" runat="server"  />
        <biw:textbox id="TextEmail" width="200" runat="server"   />
        <asp:requiredfieldvalidator controltovalidate="TextEmail" text="*" errormessage="Please enter an e-mail address" display="dynamic" runat="server" />

        <biw:emailaddressvalidator controltovalidate="TextEmail" text="*" errormessage="Please enter a valid e-mail address" display="dynamic" runat="server" />

        <asp:customvalidator id="EmailValidator" controltovalidate="TextEmail" text="*" display="dynamic" runat="server" />
    </asp:panel>
```

Comment: can you add another tag to your question to indicate the framework you're using?  it's not straight html, which is what `aria-describedby` and `aria-live` are for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`aria-describedby`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-describedby) adds additional information to an element.  An element usually has a name or label and additionally it can have a description.  If your error message is in a separate element, such as a `<div>` or `<span>`, you can associate that `<div>` with the input field.

You code might look something like:

```html
<label for="emailID">email address:</label>
<input id="emailID" aria-describedby="errorMsg">
<div id="errorMsg">invalid email address</div>
```

Some screen readers will read the `aria-describedby` after the field's label and others will tell you to hit a shortcut key to hear the description.  It's up to the screen reader to decide how to present it to the user.

If the above field were in error, then it should have [`aria-invalid="true"`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-invalid) as well.

```html
<input id="emailID" aria-describedby="errorMsg" aria-invalid="true">
```

In order for the error message to be announced by screen readers, it should have [`aria-live="polite"`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-live).

```html
<div id="errorMsg" aria-live="polite"></div>
```

When you discover an error, you insert text into the `<div>` (via javascript) and the screen reader will announce it because it's a live region.

```js
document.getElementById("errorMsg").innerHTML = "invalid email address";
```

Comment: I wouldn't use `aria-describedby`. I guess, for an error message the `alert` role is enough.

Comment: aria-describedby is **exactly** the right attribute to associate an error with an input field.  that's one of its main purposes.  using alert should be done with caution.  many screen readers will actually say "alert" and that could be annoying.  if you're filling in a form, a field in error doesn't necessarily qualify it as an alert error.  it's just a simple form error.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `aria-errormessage` to read error instead `aria-describedby` because both are similar but purpose is different.

```
<input id="emailID" aria-errormessage="errorMsg" aria-invalid="true">
```

You may find more information [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-errormessage)

Comment: Can you explain why using `aria-errormessage` is better than `aria-describedby`? You recommend using it but don't say why.

Comment: @slugolicious As you can simply identify by name that `aria-errormessage` depicts for error state which works with `aria-invalid` and `aria-describedby` is just to describe anything like label, input, link, button etc for accessibility purpose so screenreader can read and announce loudly. 
Aria-errormessage attribute behaves similarly to aria-describedby,accepting an ID reference. It becomes accessible only when aria-invalid is set to 'true' on the corresponding element. Employing a live region attribute like aria-live='polite' on the error message container element is a discretionary choice.

Comment: Unfortunately, `aria-errormessage` isn't fully supported by all screen readers. NVDA still has a [bug](https://github.com/nvaccess/nvda/issues/8318) (as of Aug 2023) that it doesn't support it. JAWS seems to support it (using the test case in the NVDA bug). Not sure about VoiceOver on Mac/iPhone.