# Accessibility issue on error and when error are removed

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility, wai-aria

I have a component called  in angular and I am using aria-live as shown below.

```
<div aria-live="polite">
<error-component></error-component>
</div>
```

This error is displayed on focus out of input field.
Now The first time when there is error, screen reader reads the error. Now I shift my focus back to input field and without making any changes I blur out of the field. So the same error is not read out this time by screen reader.
I tried it using aria-relevant but it did not solve the issue.
Also my other question is suppose the user enters correct value and then error is removed. Should the screen reader tell the user that a particular error is removed?

Comment: This is most likely because there has been no content change. aria-live tells screen readers to notify users of any changes that occur to the area. In your specific case, the content of the error message has not changed, so there is no update to the user.

Comment: Agreed @joffutt. But is there any way to make it work.

Comment: You could potentially have the blur event reset the error message and re-populate it so that every time a user focuses and un-focuses the input it would cause a change in the content.

Comment: No need to blank out the error and fill it in again.  Aria-live is for changing content, like @joffutt4 said.  Just associate the error with the input field using aria-describedby and it will be read correctly.  see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53167195/how-to-make-inline-errors-read-aloud-by-screen-reader-tools/53168237#53168237

Answer (score 1):

This may not change your outcome, but the possible aria-live settings are: `off`, `polite` or `assertive`, not `true`

[Simple Live Regions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Live_Regions)

> Normally, only aria-live="polite" is used. Any region which receives
>   updates that are important for the user to receive, but not so rapid
>   as to be annoying, should receive this attribute. The screen reader
>   will speak changes whenever the user is idle.

```
<div aria-live="polite">
<error-component></error-component>
</div>
```

There isn't a specific requirement to inform the user that the error is corrected but that's probably a nice to have.

EDIT: I see you have edited your code which was previously `<div aria-live="true">` since my answer

Answer (score 1):

For your first question, it's quite a common behavior, though not universal, for aria-live regions not to be read again if twice the same text is added/set in a row, regardless of using aria-live=polite or aria-live=assertive.
It is sometimes possible to fool this behavior by clearing and then reset the text back, but it doesn't always work.

Globally that's something you can't go against. You are guaranteed to have the new text always read only if it is different from the current text.

Aria-relevant can't help here. It just tells if additions and/or removals have to be spoken, but not if two idendical additions/reset have to be spoken once or twice.

For your second question, you may use aria-relevant so that removals are also notified. However, it isn't the best solution.
First of all because aria-relevant isn't always well supported with certain browser+screen reader combinations.
But more importantly because you have a much more reliable and much more user-approved solution for this specific case.

For your case of knowing when a field is or is no longer in error, use *aria-invalid*. Set it when the field becomes invalid, keep it set as long as the field is incorrectly filled, and ideally, remove the attribute as soon as the input becomes correct again.
Many screen readers announce immediately the change between valid and invalid, or in the worst case invalidity is announced each time the field takes the focus.

The only thing you should be careful with aria-invalid is that, you should avoid setting the field as invalid if the user hasn't yet entered anything or if he just tab through it without changing the initial value.
The same caution that you would avoid putting the field in red directly at page load.

Added precision: aria-invalid only allow to say if a field is invalid, it doesn't allow you to set a message. For this you can keep on using a separate aria-live region, or you may use aria-describedby. The advantage of aria-describedby is that the message can be repeated on demand, but it can only be applied to specific field (do not use for errors concerning the entire form in a whole or for errors that implies multiple fields at once).